# Snowflake Information_Schema - Getting client driver and application info for a particular session_id

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to get the client details (Client driver, application) from the Information_Schema for a currently running session using the session_id column, similar to what we see under the Client Driver section in the Query Details tab inside the Activity page on the Snowflake UI. Here is the query I am running:

```sql
select query_id,query_text,query_type,user_name,start_time,session_id
from table(snowflake.information_schema.query_history_by_warehouse(WAREHOUSE_NAME => 'COMPUTE_WH')) 
where  execution_time > 180000 
and EXECUTION_STATUS='RUNNING';
```

So far, I've only seen the session details being captured inside the snowflake.account_usage.sessions table, but it has latent data.

Looking for some direction here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi , check this link    https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowflake-client-version-check , ma be this could help for what you  want.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thanks for your input. I am looking to get the real-time client details (Client driver, Application name) from the information_schema views (if there is any such view) for my currently running sessions.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks, NickW! We do not have this data currently available via any information_schema views.